# MySQL statement taking abnormally long

Tags: sql, indexing, timeout, sql-update

I have two tables in one database with about 50,000 to 70,000 rows. Both are MyISAM. The first, yahooprices, contains SKU codes (column code) for items and pricing (column price). The second table, combined_stock, contains partnumber (same information as code, but sorted differently), price, quantity, and description. Price is currently defined as FLOAT 10,2 and set to 0.00. I am attempting to pull the pricing over from yahooprices (also FLOAT 10,2) to combined_stock using this statement:

```
UPDATE combined_stock dest LEFT JOIN (
SELECT price, code FROM yahooprices
) src ON dest.partnumber = src.code
SET dest.price = src.price
```

I know this statement worked because I tried it on a smaller test amount. They have partnumber and code as non-unique indexes. I also tried indexing price on both tables to see if that would speed up the query. Technically it should finish within seconds, but last time I tried running this, it sat there overnight and even then I'm pretty certain it didn't work out.  Anyone have any troubleshooting recommendations?

Comment: Share the data structure, specifically, for each table, for the relevant columns.  Data type, index (and type), etc.

Comment: Why are you doing a left join?  Even more importantly, why are you storing the same piece of data in two places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest some relatively small changes.  First, get rid of the subquery.  Second, switch to an inner join:

```
UPDATE combined_stock dest JOIN
      yahooprices src
      ON dest.partnumber = src.code
  SET dest.price = src.price;
```

Finally create an index on `yahooprices(code, price)`.

You can leave the `left outer join` if you really want the price to be set to `NULL` when there is no match.